# pymongo map-reduce example to build map function dynamically

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, pymongo

I am using pymongo map_reduce API to perform a map-reduce job on mongoDB.
   The problem that i am facing is building the map function. I have to iterate to fetch value from the "this" object. WHich i want to avoid.

if the document in mongoDB is

```
 {X:{y:{Z:10}},A:{B:20,F:30}}
To get value of Z i can do
 var value = this.X.y.Z
```

Which i can specify in map function directly (hard coded) else need to iterate thru....
So was looking for an option to build map function dynamically. some thing like

```
def buildMapFunc(string):
    basestring = "function map () { print("
    queryStr1 = basestring+string
    queryStr2 = queryStr1+")}"
    map = Code(queryStr2)
```

Can this be done? If yes can you please give example.
Thanks in advance